# Books about concurrent access to databases

Tags: database, concurrency

I need to write an essay(for *concurrent programming* subject) of different techniques of how can concurrent access to databases be implemented. And how and which of those are implemented in DBMSs.

I can't find any books nor materials to read about it. Does someone know any books I can find helpful?

Comment: I will give MacGucky's answer the acceptance cause in wikipedia's article in the references there's a book "Concurrency Control and Recovery in Database Systems" by Philip A. Bernstein, Vassos Hadzilacos and Nathan Goodman which seem to be what I was looking for. Thanks! If someone else has other books, I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know an book, but wikipedia hast an nice article about that: [Concurrency control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control)

Comment: I don't think that wikipedia is really acceptable as a source for a school paper (it seems that the OP is writing the essay for school).